# How to Search for a specific record in a .dat file by a keyword

Tags: vb.net

So i have a listbox which displays the contents of a .dat file.

Each record in the file has name,time,location and description.

On my form there is a search button which when clicked, I would like the user to be able to type in a name to check if that particular record exists. If it does, I would like a msgbox to show the entire record in the order I mentioned earlier. On the other hand if not I want a msgbox to display saying record cannot be found.

Comment: do you want us to write something for those specs or did you have a question?

Comment: Yes sorry I would love somebody to help write something

Comment: I've not really tried anything yet as I'm unsure how to really begin.

Comment: What is the actual file format of the .dat file (an example of the contents of the file would be helpful)?  How large is the file?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Its just saving standard text. its declared in my code as "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Jobs.Dat" This screenshot shows how it displays in the listbox on my program -- http://gyazo.com/1d12203ec27e4b03fbcc5cea96318030

Comment: Is it tab delimited fields, with newline characters separating each record?  Is the Name always in the first field of each record?

Comment: write code to open the file, get the data etc etc; then post a specific question when you get stuck - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BradleyUffner this my code for creating an entry to the file         Dim datatodisplay As String
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)    'Open the file'
        listdisplay.Items.Clear()                'if there is anyhting in the listbox this will be cleared
        Do While Not EOF(1)                       ' if its not the end of the file then...
            datatodisplay = LineInput(1)              'the data to display is what was input
            listdisplay.Items.Add(datatodisplay)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a tab delimited file with carrage return between records with the first field being the field you are searching (Edited to me more complete and better match the question):

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Function FindRecord(name As String, path As String) As Record
        Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
            Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
                Dim record As Record = record.FromLine(line)
                If record.Name = name Then
                    Return record
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Class Record
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Time As Date
        Public Property Location As String
        Public Property Description As String

        Public Shared Function FromLine(line As String) As Record
            Dim record As Record = Nothing

            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
            If fields.Length = 4 Then
                record = New Record
                record.Name = fields(0)
                record.Time = Date.Parse(fields(1))
                record.Location = fields(2)
                record.Description = (3)
            Else
                Throw New FormatException("Line is not in the correct format.")
            End If
            Return record
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```